# Change span text is very slow

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is my code below:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
 if(spans[i].innerHTML == "Test 2") {
    spans[i].innerHTML = "some example text";
    break;
 }
}
});//]]>  
</script>

<div class="sptests">
  <ul>
      <li id="sp_test" class=""><span>Test</span></li>
      <li id="sp_test2" class=""><span>Test 2</span></li>
      <li id="sp_test3" class=""><span>Test 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to change span text of li id="sp_test2". I used above javascript, but it's taking long time to change i.e it is first showing "Test 2" text then after page loading completes it shows changed text "some example text".

I want to change that span text with immediate effect on page loading.
Anyone plz helpme...Alternative methods also suggested.

Comment: Use `getElementByID`, rather than looping through every span?

Comment: the load event of the window object is triggered as soon as the page is fully loaded. Maybe you'd like to listen for the document.ready event?

Comment: Do you need to check every `span`? Because that's what you're doing and likely why it's slow.

Comment: How do you check for `document.ready` without jQuery?

Comment: If you've got the option to employ `querySelectorAll()` you could reduce the scope of your checks (easily) with `var spans = document.querySelectorAll('div.sptests li > span')`, or (if you have to be more cross-browser compatible) you could first search for the `li` elements, then check those for the `span` elements with the relevant text-content.

Comment: This guy gets his answers and then leaves, without marking correct etc. He then sets up a new account for his next question.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for(var i=0;i<spans.length; i++) {
 if(spans[i].innerHTML == "Test 2") {
    spans[i].innerHTML = "some example text";
    break;
 }
}
});//]]>  
</script>
```

Give that a shot. If I am correct, $(window).load waits for absolutely everything to be in place. $(document).ready should be faster.

**EDIT**

Secondly, if you are using jQuery anyway (you are, right? seen from your usage of $(window)?), you might as well use it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("sp_test2").children("span").html("Some example text");
});//]]>  
</script>

<div class="sptests">
  <ul>
      <li id="sp_test" class=""><span>Test</span></li>
      <li id="sp_test2" class=""><span>Test 2</span></li>
      <li id="sp_test3" class=""><span>Test 3</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but there's still slight delay in changing that text...any other method plz..

Comment: What happens if you move that <script> block _underneath_ the <div> block and remove the whole $(document).ready function?

Answer (score 0):

use jquery :

```
$("span").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "Test 2") {
        $(this).text('some example text');
    }
})
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but there's no [tag:jquery] tag for this question (even if jQuery *seems* to be used, from the syntax).

Comment: I think this answer adds value to this question, for other users also.

Comment: Thanks, I had just mentioned that if you want to do it jQuery way, you can do it like this :)